# How do I retrieve the year, month, day, hours and minutes from date-time string?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to extract from a tensor string `"2018/12/31 22:59"` the values of year, month, day, hour and minute. I found this function `tf.string_split` for this task, but my code is throwing an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/my/file.py", line 12, in <module>
    date = split_date_time[0]
TypeError: 'SparseTensor' object does not support indexing
```

Here's the code

```
import tensorflow as tf

date_time = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string)

day = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32),
month = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32),
year = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32),
hour = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32),
minute = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32)

split_date_time = tf.string_split(date_time, ' ')
date = split_date_time[0]
time = split_date_time[1]

date_splitted = tf.string_split(date, '-')
year = date_splitted[0]
month = date_splitted[1]
day = date_splitted[2]

time_spplitted = tf.string_split(time, ':')
hour = time_spplitted[0]
minute = time_spplitted[1]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(year, feed_dict={date_time: "2018-12-31 22:59"}))
    print (sess.run(month, feed_dict={date_time: "2018-12-31 22:59"}))
    print (sess.run(day, feed_dict={date_time: "2018-12-31 22:59"}))
    print (sess.run(hour, feed_dict={date_time: "2018-12-31 22:59"}))
    print (sess.run(minute, feed_dict={date_time: "2018-12-31 22:59"}))
```

Comment: If there's an error, you should always tell us which error and, if possible, have a complete specification of the error.

Comment: True!, thanks for the editing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems in your code (mainly because you apparently didn't read any documentation regarding the functions you're trying to use). I will just mention a few crucial problems related to the specific problem you're trying to solve (but I strongly encourage you to study the basics of TensorFlow and its computational model).

First, as the [documentation of `tf.string_split`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_split) states, the first argument of `tf.string_split` should be a "*1-D string Tensor, the strings to split*". However, `"2018-12-31 22:59"` is a 0-D string tensor.

Second, `tf.string_split` returns a [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor), which cannot be indexed!

Here's a possible solution to your problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf

date_time = tf.placeholder(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)

split_date_time = tf.string_split(date_time, ' ')

date = split_date_time.values[0]
time = split_date_time.values[1]

split_date = tf.string_split([date], '-')
split_time = tf.string_split([time], ':')

year = split_date.values[0]
month = split_date.values[1]
day = split_date.values[2]

hours = split_time.values[0]
minutes = split_time.values[1]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    year, month, day, hours, minutes = sess.run([year, month, day, hours, minutes],
                                                feed_dict={date_time: ["2018-12-31 22:59"]})
    print("Year =", year)
    print("Month =", month)
    print("Day =", day)
    print("Hours =", hours)
    print("Minutes =", minutes)
```

Comment: Thank you nbro. I really tried to follow the documentation, I spent a long time in this thing. This is my first week with Tensorflow, please bear with time. By the way, do you have any good book "for dummies" that explains intuitively Tensorflow?

Comment: @zeellos Unfortunately, I have still not found a very good book on TF (for newbies). TF is continuously evolving. I would read the official tutorials and, if you don't understand something from there, try to understand it from somewhere else (on the web).